# Computing MAE with scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am stuck on this problem:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor

def mae(prediction, target):

   return np.sum(np.abs(prediction - target)) 

knn_model = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=k)

prediction = knn_model.fit(X_train,y_train)
val_mae = mae(prediction, y_val)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.fit` returns the actual model object, you need to call `.predict` to get predictions

```
knn_model.fit(X_train,y_train)
prediction = knn_model.predict(X_val)
val_mae = mae(prediction, y_val)
```